# What are the steps to becoming a rules advisor and what kind of rulings can be made by one?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play FNMs at a relatively small store. There isn't a judge that runs the FNMs or any that consistently play there (the crowd is casual for the most part). I know the rules fairly well and the people that play at the store trust me enough to ask rules questions. I want to take the rules advisor test so that there's at least a semi-official source for answers to rules questions at these FNMs.

What steps are there to taking the test and becoming a rules advisor (ie: do you need to talk to a judge as if you were trying to become a L1)? What types of rulings are rules advisors allowed to make?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The Rules Advisor program has recently been discontinued. Becoming a level 1 judge is the entry level for officially judging.**

The changes in a nutshell:

> 1. The Rules Advisor exam is available until the end of April. Passing the exam no longer grants or renews the Rules Advisor membership, and all existing memberships will expire normally. Once the exam is retired, all content in that exam pool will be either reassigned to another exam or retired from use.
> 2. The online L1 Practice exam is now available to all users. People interested in becoming a judge now have direct access to this resource, and this exam shows up on your Judge Center profile when you pass it. (Keep in mind that passing the L1 Practice exam does not grant any special benefit or membership.) **If a particular store truly wants to require something to judge FNM, passing the L1 Practice exam is a far more reasonable requirement and more supportive of organized play in the long term since it helps lead towards Level 1 certification.**
> 3. The online L1 Practice exam now has a 28-day cooldown period. This should make for a training resource that is more readily available to all users, balancing the limited content in the pool with the need to make sure people can study and practice towards earning the Level 1 certification. Level 2 and Level 3 judges can still create the online L1 Practice exam for others, and still have the ability to generate written L1 Practice exams to administer in person. Use the resource as necessary to help people to pass and join the judge community.

Source: http://blogs.magicjudges.org/blog/2016/04/15/the-rules-advisor-exam-is-being-discontinued/

Comment: Well that answers that. Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of that change.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the program at all, so there's that. Please forgive the snark, but my process of arriving at the answer was to google "rules advisor" and finding that link in 3rd from top, so I suppose basic googling techniques would be a good first step towards becoming a judge ^^

Comment: I was using the terms "mtg rules advisor test" and found plenty of discussion on studying for it but nothing about the program being canceled.

Comment: It would probably be useful to point out that while it is preferred you don't have to be a L1+ Judge to be a judge (or even head judge) of a tournament (MTR 1.7 and 1.8). And if you are a (Head) Judge at a tournament you have the ability to make the exact same rulings regardless of level.

Comment: @Hackworth I'm seeing some strange inconsistency: if I search Google for "rules advisor" or "mtg rules advisor", I don't see that post anywhere in the first page of results.

Comment: Well it does for me, at least for "rules advisor". It already fails to show up for "mtg rules advisor" though. Additionally, Google results can differ based on which country one is searching from, and AFAIK google by default uses your country based on IP, and it's not trivially changed. You'd have to use at least a proxy to get a different country's google.

Comment: @Hackworth As far as search results go (not ads) all you need to do is go to google.com and use the 'google.com' link in the bottom right (and if logged in switch to 'hide private results' in the top right after searching).